# Returning an Object stream with a file source

Tags: java, file, memory

I'm currently implementing an interface with one method that returns a stream of objects. For the implementation I'm reading from a file and deserializing the lines. Unfortunately this means I'm not able to close the `BufferedReader`/`FileReader` as I need it open for the consumer of the stream. Have people ran into a similar issue like this? How did you approach it/is there really any safe way to do this that doesn't result in resources being left uncleaned up? The file is large so I wouldn't want to read it all into memory.

```java
public class ObjectStreamerImpl implements ObjectStreamer {
    @Override
    public Stream<Object> getObjectStream() {
        return new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("my/file/path.txt"))).lines()
            .map(line -> convertToObject(line));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Stream` is `AutoClosable`  so any resources allocated for the stream can be handled effectively with try-with resources:

```
try(var stream = getObjectStream()) {
    // do work with stream here
}
```

Then fix the `getObjectStream` to avoid using BufferedReader - it isn't necessary, you can change to `Path` and `Files.lines()`:

```
public Stream<Object> getObjectStream() throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Path.of("my/file/path.txt"))
        .map(line -> convertToObject(line));
        // Or .map(this::convertToObject)
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, also added an onClose handler to the stream to delete the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep track of the `BufferedReader` so that you can close it later. One approach is to make `ObjectStreamerImpl` closable.

```java
class ObjectStreamerImpl implements ObjectStreamer, Closeable {

    private BufferedReader reader;

    public ObjectStreamerImpl() throws FileNotFoundException {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my/file/path.txt"));
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Object> getObjectStream() {
        return reader.lines().map(line -> convertToObject(line));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Then use the try-with-resources block.

```java
try (ObjectStreamerImpl streamer = new ObjectStreamerImpl()) {
    // streamer.getObjectStream()...
}
```